Can I reconnect my stolen HVAC unit using the cut wires?
Just received my stolen HVAC unit back. The wires were cut. Is it possible to get it replaced with same wires?

The wires that are brought to the outside of the unit from the inside, are typically added at the time of install. It should be of no consequence.

I tweaked things for more readability, and I added the question I think you're asking. If I have misinterpreted, please feel free to edit further.

Replacing wires is easy, just get the same size and type.  The unit itself might be damaged(maybe hidden inside) from being taken and returned.

Please add a photo of the location and a closeup of the cut wires and where they come from (junction box, wall, etc).

Yes, LCDI cords are replaceable.
